# How to improve a if statement checking every TypeScript interface properties?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following interface

```
interface Ver {
  mi: string,
  ma: string,
  ha: string,
  rev: string
}
```

which I don't want to print out in the following case (where `ver` is an object implementing `Ver` interface)

```
if(!ver || (!ver.mi && !ver.ma && !ver.ha && !ver.rev)) {
  return '';
}
```

Question is: is there a better TypeScript-compliant way to shorten this `if` statement test (especially this `(!ver.mi && !ver.ma && !ver.ha && !ver.rev)` part ?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the properties and check if they're all truthy.

```js
const hasAllValues = <T extends object>(obj: T) => Object.values(obj).every(value => value);

if (!ver || !hasAllValues(ver)) {
  return '';
}
```

This may cause problems if obj contains more keys than is in Ver. In this case you could manually define the properties to check:

```js
const props = ['mi', 'ma', 'ha', 'rev'];

const hasAllProperties = <T extends object, P extends keyof T>(obj: T, props: P) => props.every(prop => obj[prop]);

if (!ver || !hasAllProperties(ver, props)) {
  return '';
}
```